# fast data search using java from oracle database

Tags: java, caching, hashmap, binary-tree, memcached

In an Oracle database I have like more than 178692 rows regarding to a store items. I need to develop regular web application  using java and front-end will be plain html. is there any caching modular way to retrieve data from the front-end.

Bellow are my column headers and are all String of data type.

```
enterITM_DESC = *CHOCBOX WHITE CHOCOLA.BAR 50G,
ITEM_CODE=GRCO66760,
PLU_CODE =23270 code here
```

I need my searching functionality to be implemented item_desc and item_code will be the key for any instance.
Your help matters a lot thanks in advance.

Comment: "178692 columns"? Do you mean rows? if not you have to re-think your table design.

Comment: You will need indexes, unless you are meaning that you will show all 178692 rows.  If so then see comment above.

Comment: Sorry I meant rows, I maintain indexes and will not output all the rows at once. I do not have an idea how index can help me to search an item by ITM_DESC

Comment: @Gayashan check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work